# Why Am I getting this Input Error?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

I want to make a dynamic mask so if the number in the textbox's length is more than 11, it should be a different mask.

I have the following code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs"     Inherits="WebApp_MVP.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#TextBoxDoc").keydown(function () {
            try {
                $("#TextBoxDoc").unmask();
            } catch (e) { }

        var tamanho = $("#TextBoxDoc").val().length;

        if (tamanho < 11) {
            $("#TextBoxDoc").mask("999.999.999-99");
        } else if (tamanho >= 11) {
            $("#TextBoxDoc").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
        }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="TextBoxDoc"><asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to write the document number, it only keeps one character, and keeps changing the last one like this:

> [______________] *presses 3
>
> [3_____________] *presses 2
>
> [2_____________] *presses 9
>
> [9_____________] and so on...

Comment: What do you mean it keeps one and changes the last one?

Comment: When I press one number, it erases the last one for example:

[                    ] *presses 3
[3__.___.___-__] *presses 2
[2_.___.___/____-__] *presses 9
[9_.___.___/____-__] 

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using unmask and remask (which I believe is removing your information) Try using 'on the fly' mask changes.

```
var options =  {onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options){
  var masks = ['999.999.999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99'];
    mask = (cep.length > 11) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
  $('#TextBoxDoc').mask(mask, options);
}};

$('#TextBoxDoc').mask('999.999.999-99', options);
```

see https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: I tried this, but it keeps static in the first mask, I don't have the chance to add a digit, so the mask will change

Comment: Where did you get your jquery.maskedinput.js file from?

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/blob/master/src/jquery.mask.js